# HTML Form Redirection

Tags: html

How to redirect to two different php pages by clicking two different buttons from one html page?

I have two buttons say btn1 and btn2

- If I click btn1, the html page page should redirect to page1.php with form values.
- In the same way, if I click btn2, the html page page should redirect to page2.php with form values.

How to do it?